# What is a template cache?

Tags: go

I'm confused with this code that I wrote it by watching golang course. Please explain me what will `*template.Template` contain? It is called template cache so what is this exactly? And why `config.go` has `TemplateCache` field and `RenderTemplate` refers to it? I guess it is dependency injection and so far dependency injection and pointers are the most confusing things for me in golang

render.go

```
var functions = template.FuncMap{}
var app *config.AppConfig

// NewTemplates sets the config for the template package
func NewTemplates(a *config.AppConfig) {
    app = a
}

// RenderTemplate
func RenderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string) {
    var tc map[string]*template.Template

    // if statement enables development mode
    if app.UseCache {
        //get the template cache from the app config

        tc = app.TemplateCache
    } else {
        tc, _ = CreateTemplateCache()
    }

    t, ok := tc[tmpl]
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("couldnt get template from template cache in render.go (37)")
    }

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    _ = t.Execute(buf, nil)
    _, err := buf.WriteTo(w)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error writing template to browser in render.go (44)", err)
    }
}

// CreateTemplateCache creates template cache as a map
func CreateTemplateCache() (map[string]*template.Template, error) {
    myCache := map[string]*template.Template{}

    pages, err := filepath.Glob("./templates/*page.html")
    fmt.Println("List of all pages that matches '*page.html': ", pages)
    if err != nil {
        return myCache, err
    }

    for _, page := range pages {
        name := filepath.Base(page)
        fmt.Println("Page is currently", page)
        fmt.Println("template.New return value: ", template.New(name))

        ts, err := template.New(name).Funcs(functions).ParseFiles(page)
        if err != nil {
            return myCache, err
        }

        matches, err := filepath.Glob("./templates/*.layout.html")
        if err != nil {
            return myCache, err
        }

        if len(matches) > 0 {
            ts, err = ts.ParseGlob("./templates/*.layout.html")
            if err != nil {
                return myCache, err
            }
        }

        myCache[name] = ts
    }
    return myCache, nil
}
```

config.go

```
// AppConfig holds the application config
type AppConfig struct {
    UseCache      bool
    TemplateCache map[string]*template.Template
}
```

Comment: The template cache exists so that templates have to be compiled only once. Without it, the same template(s) would have to be compiled repeatedly for every request, a waste of CPU cycles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs at [pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev) Template is a struct that contains one field named Tree with type *parse.Tree. If we go to parse package we see that

> Tree is the representation of a single parsed template.

As to your question about what `TemplateCache` is, it's as it sounds.

> In computing, a cache is a high-speed data storage layer which stores a subset of data

So the `TemplateCache` stores template for future use and access. When `RenderTemplate` runs, it builds the template from scratch using the html/tmpl files to a format (`template.Template`) that Go can work with and render.

A naive version of the `RenderTemplate` function would be calling it after every request in all the different handlers each time they are called but what the `RenderTemplate` function does is that it's getting called only once at the beginning of the application in `main.go` and build all the templates and store them in the `TemplateCache` for future use.